# How to deploy/upload a JSP file on Server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have created a jsp file which will give an output in JSON format using java class and servlet, i am new to java and i don't have idea about the deployment of jsp file. Can anyone suggest me how to do it? I used to develop an asp.net web application in which there was a specific option available which called " publish project", but i cant find in eclipse.
I already have a php server in which i have uploaded few php files, can i use the same server to upload this file?

Currently, my application is running fine on localhost.

Please help me with this matter and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish your project in Eclipse:

1. Right click your project
2. Export
3. Under Web > Choose WAR
4. Then just follow the instructions and your good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do i need to upload this file to another internet server because i assume that apache server is running on my local machine but i need to use this .war file into another software by calling a url of jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

It is done as a component of a [WAR (Web Application Archive)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) file.

Upon deployment, JSP files are processed by the Servlet container.  The processing effectively turns them into Servlets, such that the plain text of the JSP becomes println statements in the response of the Servlet, and the embedded Java code in the JSP becomes regular Java code in the Servlet.

[The packaging details are covered in detail in the JEE7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/packaging003.htm), although earlier tutorials don't differ much in the details.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using tomcat in your php? you can use tomcat or glassfish server to deploy your application. you just need the `.war` file of your application and upload it to the admin page of tomcat or glassfish server.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, i have a php domain and a database for IOS application, bascially i have created an IOS app which will call a jsp website to get an output and it also calls a php file when it requires, my project required to create php and jsp files. Secondly, where can i find .war file ? i can see web.xml file in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: jsp files are associated with .war file that you need to deploy. so it is not posible to execute only the jsp file, i think i got your question correctly?

Comment: yes, fortunately you understood correctly, :) well now i have created a war file and as per my assumption i need to upload this .war file to tomcat server so i can use it from any other machine. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please provide me a link of tomcat server where i can upload my file? hope you don't mind @Ker. :)

Comment: you can upload it locally with your apache tomcat server. i've been using [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) in uploading my .war files and you can access the project using your public ip and port of the tomcat(default is 8080)

Answer (score 0):

It should be in `.war` file format

Here are few links which can help you in building it from eclipse, [link1](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrewar.html), [link2](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse.html).

For deployment, there should be a server -- tomcat / glassfish / jboss which can provide platform to execute `.war` files.

Answer (score 0):

IDEs and .war files are great productivity tools, but I'm of a mind that you need to understand how these things work from the command line. I'm using Apache Tomcat running on a Raspberry Pi as a development server. I developed my .jsp and then just copied to where it needed to be. In this example login.jsp needs to be in the root folder of an app called SEM. So, just copy it there and access it via its URL.

```
sudo cp login.jsp $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/SEM

http://localhost:8080/SEM/login.jsp
```

Didn't even have to restart Tomcat. :)